# Evaluating improper integral $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{0}^{1} (\frac{\phi(x)}{x+i\epsilon}- \frac{\phi(x)}{x-i\epsilon}) dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration

> I want to evaluate the improper integral $$\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_0^1{\left( \frac{\phi \left( x \right)}{x+i\epsilon}-\frac{\phi \left( x \right)}{x-i\epsilon} \right)}dx
> $$ where $\phi(x) : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

What I’ve tried is just simplify integrand as $\displaystyle  \frac{2i\epsilon \phi(x)}{x^2 + \epsilon^2}$.

I just guess it can be evaluated by some complex analytic method since the integrand involves $i$. But I can’t see how to use what I know(basic residue theorem, cauchy’s integral formula, etc.).

Could you give a direction to solve this? I appreciate your comment and answer.

Comment: We only know that $\phi$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.  We are not given that $\phi(z)$ is analytic is some open domain of the complex plane.  Therefore, we cannot extend $\phi$ by analytic continuation and apply Cauchy's Integral Theorem.  I provided a solution using real analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we can write for $\varepsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \phi(x)\frac{-2i\varepsilon}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}\,dx&=-2i\int_0^{1/\varepsilon} \phi(\varepsilon x)\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&=-2i\int_0^\infty \phi(\varepsilon x)\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,\xi_{[0,1/\varepsilon]}(x)\,dx\\\\
\end{align}$$

Since $\left|\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,\xi_{[0,1/\varepsilon]}(x)\right|\le g(x)= \max_{[0,1]}\{\phi\}\frac1{x^2+1}$ and $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx<\infty$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_0^1 \phi(x)\frac{-2i\varepsilon}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}\,dx&=-2i\int_0^\infty \lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\phi(\varepsilon x)\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,\xi_{[0,1/\varepsilon]}(x)\,dx\\\\&=-i\pi\phi(0)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Where can I learn this method? though I learned introductory real analysis...

Comment: [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) is a reference.  And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Comment: From the second equation to the third equation, what did you do?what is $\xi$?

Comment: And I guess you assumed $\varepsilon \gt 0$, didn't you?

Comment: @glimpser Yes, the limit is taken from the right.